# Mustash cache issue in EE2.10

Tags: stash, cache, mustash

I've been working with Stash and Mustash on every single one of my EE projects. What I usually do, is caching my detail-pages to a bundle. So sorta like, for example:

```
{exp:stash:cache bundle="products"}
```

If I then go and look at my cached variables inside this bundle, I get stuff like `product/1:cache` or `product/2:cache`. Which is good, as each possible detail-page has it's own stash variable.

On my most recent project though, I use the same workflow, and get this instead:

```
[index]:cache
```

This is not good. This is not unique, so everytime I visit a detail-page in this bundle, it's always exactly the same as the first one viewed and stuffed as a stash variable.

The big difference in this project is that I've updated it from 2.1.2 to 2.10. I've never used Stash and Mustash on EE2.10 before.

What's happening? And how can I fix this? :)

Thanks!

Comment: You might try adding a 'context' parameter to cache tag to check that the pages are being cached separately (i.e.  context={segment_1}_{segment_2}  ).

Comment: Thanks! That could work to some extent. But it worked without before. Also, I think this is quite a bit of extra work. Especially for detailpages. I'm also using freebie, so sometimes a segment should actually be freebie etc.